# How to set text in next line inside a Vuetify chip?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to set the text in two different lines inside a vuetify chip but i have tried a couple of different approach. Even setting own rows for each part of text but it still seems to be in the same line. Any ideas on how to fix it?

This is a sample [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/pojyeQY)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {};
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex xs5>
          <v-chip close>
            <v-layout>
              Hello !!
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout>
              <div> There </div>
            </v-layout>
          </v-chip>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

So essentially Hello and There should be in next line!! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a simple `<br/>` tag?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {};
  }
});
```

```css
.v-chip .v-chip__content {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout xs4>
        <v-chip close>
          Hello !!<br/> There
        </v-chip>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: No i did not but hey that was Great!! Thank you so much!!